# Возможность использования коротких тегов PHP

Tags: php, yii2, apache2

Существует проект в котором осуществляется следующая запись:

```
                        <? if (!isset($item['title']) || !isset($item['text'])):?>

                        <? break; ?>

                    <? endif; ?>
```

выдает ошибку, если же изменю код на следующий:

```
                        <?php if (!isset($item['title']) || !isset($item['text'])):?>

                        <?php break; ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>
```

тогда все заработает, пользуюсь ubuntu, сервер apache2, пробовал поменять short_open_tag: 
;   short_open_tag=On
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off
все равно не работает, выручайте)

Comment: короткие теги являются устаревшими и будут удалены из  будущих релизов

Comment: Ок, а я могу сейчас включить поддержку такой записи или что для этого нужно сделать ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Установить значение директивы `short_open_tag = On` в конфигурационном файле `php.ini`.
2. Перезапустить сервер Apache.

Но использование коротких тегов не рекомендуется, т.к. начиная с версии PHP 7.4 они будут считаться [устаревшими](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_php_short_tags). Также использование короткой записи не рекомендуется стандартом кодирования [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#1-overview).